# How to use Filters in boto3 python to return multiple subnets(values)?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, pytest, boto3

I'm using `boto3` library to query subnetIDS from AWS EC2 Resource(VPC) that start with `my-private-*`. How can I use Filters to get multiple subnet ID's that match the tag value 'my-private-*'?

In this first legacy function, I was able to query and return a list private_subnet_ids which contained multiple subnetID's

```
def get_private_subnet_ids():
        """
        Retrieves the Private Subnet IDs of VPC with the Tag Name - my-private
        :return:
        """
        private_subnet_ids = []
        subnets = vpc_client.describe_subnets()
        for subnet in subnets['Subnets']:
            if 'Tags' in subnet:
                for tag in subnet['Tags']:
                    if tag['Key'] == 'Name' and tag['Value'].startswith('my-private'):
                        private_subnet_ids.append(subnet['SubnetId'])
        return private_subnet_ids
```

I changed my function to use Filters instead of above but it's only returns a single element. Is there a way to use Filters and still be able to return multiple subnets?
The below refactored function only returns one element of the list and not multiple subnet id's

```
def private_subnet_exists():
    subnet = []
    subnet = vpc_client.describe_subnets(
        Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:Name', 'Values': ['my-private-*']}])['Subnets']
    if len(subnet) > 0:
        return subnet[0]['SubnetId']
    else:
        return None
```

Comment: Why do you return only the first subnet? Shouldn't you do something like `return [s['SubnetId'] for s in subnet]`?

Comment: That solved it :) Thanks again. You can post your answer and I can mark it as a solution

Comment: Glad to help, though I don't think this is interesting enough for someone else to make into an answer - it's just a standard list comprehension.